# Was it acceptable to close Question B instead of Question A?

Tags: discussion

I closed the question [**Do owls have to have training?**](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/27579/do-owls-have-to-have-training?noredirect=1) (asked on 12.04.12) in favor of [**How was Hedwig able to find Sirius?**](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/137791/how-was-hedwig-able-to-find-sirius) (asked on 08.13.16).

I feel the Hedwig question is more precise and provides an answer that is better grounded in canon; it quotes Pottermore. The answer to the owl training question references one of the *Harry Potter* movies as its source, making it lower on the HP canon hierarchy than Pottermore.

**Was I in any way obligated to select the newer question for closure? Was choosing an older, more established question for closure acceptable?**

I was thinking a question's quality and relevance are ultimately more important considerations than when a question was asked and answered, which is wholly incidental.

<sub>I sometimes have a hard time discerning true duplicates and close questions when I shouldn't (Of course I reverse the closure if it's explained to me why I'm wrong in a way that makes sense.). So, I don't always feel super confident when I close a question, hence me bringing this to meta.</sub>

Comment: yes, this happens all the time. the better question/answer should stay open

Comment: see also: http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/4744/should-we-always-close-the-newer-question-as-the-duplicate

Comment: The ***better*** question should stay open, not just the earlier.

Comment: Thanks, all! (Sorry for asking a duplicate question about duplicates <facepalm> )